# can't get value in code-behind after jQuery appends to asp:Listbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've created 2 asp:listbox... asp:ListboxFrom and asp:ListboxTo. When I double click on the item on ListboxFrom it moves (appends) the item to ListboxTo... So everything works fine till here. But when I click on the submit button to process everything I don't get the selected items in my code-behind for the listboxes. I debugged on Page_Init and Page_load but it restores the default controlstate values.... So what am I missing now?

1) How can I get the values in code-behind ? so the state of asp:listbox as it is added client-side code.
2) another question: when it appends to the ListboxTo the items are selected per default (they are blue). How can I avoid this?

thanks for helping,

below is the simple JQuery code I use in aspx,

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="listboxFrom" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
  <asp:ListBox ID="listboxTo" SelectionMode="Multiple" />


   $(function() {
    $('select[id$=dnn_ctr658_ViewAgenda_Invoer_listboxFrom]').bind("dblclick", function() {
        $("select[id$=dnn_ctr658_ViewAgenda_Invoer_listboxFrom] option:selected").appendTo("#dnn_ctr658_ViewAgenda_Invoer_listboxTo");
    });

    $('select[id$=dnn_ctr658_ViewAgenda_Invoer_listboxTo]').bind("dblclick", function() {

        $("select[id$=dnn_ctr658_ViewAgenda_Invoer_listboxTo] option:selected").appendTo("#dnn_ctr658_ViewAgenda_Invoer_listboxFrom");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a security thing. I wonder why aspnet doesn´t throw a warning exception for an unauthorized element manipulation...

You will have to create either a custom element or u use a hiddenfield. But please be very carefull with data, lists that everybody can change on client side. Everybody could insert items in your dropdown and make it selected...

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for answering. But this is a natural thing. I've 2 x asp:listbox. I don't want to do postback so I use jQuery when they double click on the item on ListboxFrom which moves to ListboxTo. so the question : since everything is changed client-side how can get the changes on ListboxFrom and ListboxTo on server-side (code behind)... what do you mean security issue and hiddenfield? I didn't understand this... thanks for your reply... or let me ask this: You don't want to do postback. How would you move items from ListboxFrom to ListboxTo without postback and get changes on code-behind

Comment: no, it´´s like if you create to dropdowns on server, the data is saved in viewstate, the count of the items in the dropdown and the items itself. They are then reproduced when you postback. To move items from dropdown to dropdown or listbox is not natural at all. Because every little hacker could insert data he wants... You have to save the "move" action somewhere, for example in hiddenfield, and reproduce the action on server side.

Comment: so do you mean I need to create an <asp:hiddenfield id="hiddenFieldRightListBoxValues" runat=server/> hieden field. and when appending to rightbox I also need to append the selecteditem to this hiddenfield. right?  When I do postback do I get the values from this hiddenfield then? right?

Comment: yeah, and validte them as much as you can!! Check what items where copied, and if this items, all of them, exists in your main collection, so nobody can create custom ones. they would be saved on your server.